# How do I get Google to index a page which is using endless scroll

Tags: ajax, seo

I have been reading [Googles article](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) on crawling Ajax Sites. I have an application which works a bit like Pinterest, which means that there is a front page with endless scroll. All the data are loaded through Ajax.

When you access the site at e.g. www.mydomain.com it adds the following to the url through JavaScript www.mydomain.com#!page=1. I can then respond to _escaped_fragment_=page=1.

My question is how do I tell Google, that instead of crawling www.mydomain.com, it should crawl www.mydomain.com#!page=1?

Also how can I tell Google that there are more pages, without having a link to those (they are shown by scrolling down)?

Comment: See: [Ajax Load More for Search Engine Bots](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/46732/1253)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to build in pagination that Googlebot will be able to follow and discover all of your content. You could probably hide the paging when you've determined the visitor has javascript enabled and your infinite scroll will work.

The bonus is that your site will be accessible to visitors without javascript.

Some good answers here on SEOmoz:
http://www.seomoz.org/q/infinite-scrolling-vs-pagination-on-an-ecommerce-site

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, let's remember that in order for a webpage to be indexed, it needs to be crawled by Google's spiders. In order for them to do that, they need text, among other things. However there are many things that will keep the spiders away, or will make their task harder: ajax is one of them. Flash is another good example of something that will keep spiders away. It's harder for them to crawl through it, so they will stay away.

Hence, most will tell you to stay away from ajax if you intend on getting a lot of search engine traffic, in the same way that people will tell you to limit the amount of flash you use on your site. But I wouldn't say that you shouldn't use ajax: in fact, based on what your describing, your application seems very neat, and I don't believe that you should compromise your design for something like this. Let's remind ourselves that there are tons of sites out there that are based on flash (I mention flash a lot because it has a similar effect on search engines to ajax), but which rank very well: YouTube is a perfect example.

But how do they do it? Simply by compensating for the "unfriendly" code that google doesn't like with a lot of content. Content that stays fresh, may I add. YouTube stays on top of things because of all the commenting that goes on: comment 24/7, which adds content constantly, and it is unique content. All other sites that use a lot of flash/ajax/etc that rank well have the same thing going for them.

So, all in all, what I'm really saying is that if you want your site and webpages to get indexed, although you use ajax, you need to compensate with as much content as you can get. Google needs content to index you. And it would be preferable if that content were knew and updated frequently: there's a reason why blogs rank so well.

Edit: SEOMoz, one of the leading SEO websites, has a few write-ups about this as well. What I described is my take on it, but there seem to be more technical ways of surpassing this problem: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate